# Does context API face any trouble with Nextjs 13.4?

Tags: react-context, next.js13

I am new to Next.js 13. I understand context API is stable with Next 13 and I followed the docs exactly to create a context to contain my access token. I also wrapped the {children} in layout.js with the provider. But Next is throwing an error as given below.

"Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: [object Object]. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function."

It will be great if someone can guide here.

```js
// AuthProvider.js 

'use client';

import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState('');

    // console.log(auth)

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

```js
// layout.js

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import AuthProvider from '@/context/AuthProvider';

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <main className="app">
          <section>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="card o-card">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>
                  {/* {children} */}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

I saw some videos and also went through official Next 13 docs. But there aren't enough content on the web to help me out of this.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm encountering the same error.